# Distributed Computing applications

Tags: java, .net, linux, distributed, hadoop

Map reduce/Hadoop is one of the framework/program that s used for distributed systems.

What are some other popular frameworks/programs?

Comment: -1 Too vague for a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are always our good friends

- [Google on distributed computing](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&ie=UTF-8&q=distributed+computing+system)
- [Wikipedia on distributed computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing)

There have been decades of computer science research on this as well as countless private and public research endeavors -- so it would help if you could focus the question a little.

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative is [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/). It works rather well and the setup of the software is relatively simple when compared to Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

Two that springs into my mind that would be considered programs that enable distributed computing.

For C/C++ there's [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) (Remote Procedure Calls), [DCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Computing_Environment) (Distributed Computing Environment) [Corba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corba), for .NET there's [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) (Windows Communication Foundation).

There are other middleware frameworks, open source and commercial that caters for distributed computing. One open source project that comes to mind when I was doing my Bachelor's degree thesis a few years ago was [FreeDCE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freedce/). A commercial one was Entera which was by Borland.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to throw in [Netezza](http://www.netezza.com/). An interesting, hardware based solution to distributed data processing.

Answer (score 1):

akka(akka.io), a toolkit and runtime for building highly concurrent, distributed, and fault tolerant event-driven applications on the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

- CORBA
- MPI (Message passing interface)